# Accessing deployed app on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

This is a noob question but I couldn't really find a way to do so.

I have a running installation of nise-bosh on my server. Now I tried to git clone and push this app onto the cloud - https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music and was successful in pushing it on the cloud. And so it provides me with a certain URL. But how do I access the app using the URL? I tried accessing it with

```
<IP_address>/<URL>
```

or

```
<URL>
```

or

```
<IP_address>.<URL>
```

But all of them are failing with an error 404. Even a curl doesn't return anything from my server machine. Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

"cf apps" shows urls for every application in CF. If an app not accessible using the url it means smth wrong with the app or routing settings.

Comment: Is there any way to get the url of specific app?

Comment: Yes, `cf app <app-name>`